# How to set bitmap on existing bitmap as its background

Tags: android, android-image

I have two bitmap lets say bitmapA and bitmapB. I want to set bitmapA as background of bitmapB
and I have to perform this on runtime.Give me some idea how can I do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `setImageDrawable(Drawable d)` will set you the Image
 
    `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d)` will set you Background in ImageView Type

And for converting your Bitmap to Drawable use this

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

check [Layer Drawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html).. Hope this is what you want..

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    bmp1 = convertToMutable(bmp1);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp1);
    bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp2, bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
    return bmp1;
}
```

You may not want to stretch the images however in which case dont use`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`